# How to send ClientId and ClientSecret in a POST instead in the header with ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

My batch must connect to a web-service using OAuth2 with the grant-type Client Credential

Here is the code :

```
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resource = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();

    resource.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
    resource.setClientId(clientId);
    resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);

    ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider provider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();     
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = provider.obtainAccessToken(resource, new DefaultAccessTokenRequest());
```

When this code is executed it make a request where grant_type is in a post value, but the clientId and the client secret are put in the header with the classic basic auth header :

```
    Authorization: Basic bXktY2xpZW50LWlkIDpteS1jbGllbnQtc2VjcmV0
```

if I decode the string bXktY2xpZW50LWlkIDpteS1jbGllbnQtc2VjcmV0

```
    decode64(bXktY2xpZW50LWlkIDpteS1jbGllbnQtc2VjcmV0) -> my-client-id:my-client-secret
```

Which is usually fine. But the web service we must use does not support this and we have to put the client-id and the client-secret in a post value like the grant-type.

Is there a way  to  achieve that ? a way to configure how client-id and client-secret are sent ?

Michael

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a method `setClientAuthenticationScheme` in `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails` class. Its default is `AuthenticationScheme.header`, you probably need to set it to `AuthenticationScheme.form`.

Comment: That was looking good but resource.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form); didn't change anything in the request. I check if I don't miss something.

Comment: My fault ! resource.set**Client**AuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form); works! Thanks